# C# Using CloudProxySharp gone wrong

Tags: c#

I want to download the code of a web page but it sends me to a captcha when I am in the presence of a proxy, without it it works fine. I tested with HttpClientHandler and I assigned a proxy. So I searched on the net how to achieve this? I found the CloudProxySharp, which can manage to fill the captcha while being connected to a proxy but either I misunderstood its use or it does not work. By the way, it is my IP that is used during the request and not the one of the proxy. I checked using a simple IP API. I would like to know, you who surely have more experience, why it is my IP that is used and not that of the proxy? 
If you need more infos, tell me please.

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var handler2 = new ClearanceHandler("http://139.99.74.79:8080")
    {
        UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0",
        MaxTimeout = 60000,
    };


    var client = new HttpClient(handler2);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://v4.ident.me/");

    var s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Comment: If there's a captcha, that's a good sign that the website you're trying to access doesn't wish for you to access the site in that way. Have you tried checking with them to see if there's an official API you can make use of rather than trying to bypass their security?

Comment: Thank's for replied ! I don't know, it's just for fun and try but I don't think so